# XSLT Add nested element to the last node based on the existing element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML, the XML has multiple occurance of 'item' elements, and there will be single occurance of 'info' element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<root xmlns="http://temo.com/tempe.xsd">


<di>    
<md>2013-07-09T09:43:00</md>
</di>


<list>

<item>
<Name>test</Name>
<section block1="true">
<block1>
<move>1</move>
<info>
<item1>test item 1</item1>
<item2>false</item2>
<item3>1</item3>
</info>
</block1>
<block2>
...
</block2>
</section>
</item>
</list>

<option>
...
</option>

</root>
```

and I want to convert it to the below format, i.e.,  if 'move' element is present then add new elements in the last position of 'info' element should be created

```
<item4>
 <item5>1</item5>
</item4>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<root xmlns="http://temo.com/tempe.xsd">


<di>    
<md>2013-07-09T09:43:00</md>
</di>


<list>

<item>
<Name>test</Name>
<section block1="true">
<block1>
<move>1</move>
<info>
  <item1>test item 1</item1>
  <item2>false</item2>
  <item3>1</item3>
  <item4>
    <item5>1</item5>
  </item4>
</info>
</block1>
  <block2>
    ...
  </block2>
</section>
</item>
<item>
    ...
</item>
</list>
<option>
...
</option>

</root>
```

I am using the following XSLT to convert to the above format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/info/*[position()=last()]">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="/section/block/move">
<!--Add new element item4-->
<xsl:element name="item4">
<xsl:element name="item5">
<xsl:value-of select="section/block/move"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:call-template name="identity" />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could you please Help me to find the issue in the XSLT?
I am new to XSLT

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a default namespace declaration on the input XML and the output XML also needs that namespace for the elements to be inserted so you need

xmlns:tp="http://temo.com/tempe.xsd"

on your `xsl:stylesheet` root element, then you need to adapt your paths and patterns to use that prefix e.g. instead of `info` you need `tp:info` and instead of `section/block/move` you need `tp:section/tp:block/tp:move` and so on.

The paths in your XSLT sample seem wrong however you use `/section/block/move` but your root element is `root` so `/section` will never select anything, even if you add the namespace prefix. And your path has `block`, the input has `block1`.

Instead of trying to fix your code I wrote a new stylesheet, it is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://temo.com/tempe.xsd"
  xmlns:tp="http://temo.com/tempe.xsd"
  exclude-result-prefixes="tp"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:param name="to-insert" xml:space="preserve">
<item4>
 <item5><xsl:value-of select="//tp:section/tp:block1/tp:move"/></item5>
</item4>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tp:item[.//tp:move[. = 1]]//tp:info">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$to-insert"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It outputs

```
<root xmlns="http://temo.com/tempe.xsd">


<di>
<md>2013-07-09T09:43:00</md>
</di>


<list>

<item>
<Name>test</Name>
<section block1="true">
<block1>
<move>1</move>
<info>
<item1>test item 1</item1>
<item2>false</item2>
<item3>1</item3>

<item4 xmlns:tp="http://temo.com/tempe.xsd">
 <item5>1</item5>
</item4>
</info>
</block1>
<block2>
...
</block2>
</section>
</item>
</list>

<option>
...
</option>

</root>
```

Comment: I have a question, I have changed template match to "pc:Signal[.//pc:StationSetReference[. = number()]]//pc:Data" because the "move" element can have any numeric value. The parameter -  $to-insert always returns the first match value of the move element. Is it possible to get the current "move" element value.

Comment: Yes, instead of the `<xsl:copy-of select="$to-insert"/>` put the elements in there directly i.g. `<item4><item5><xsl:value-of select="../tp:move"/></item5></item4>`.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I tried parent::pc:info/pc:move/node() it is giving the current value.